# On the definition of irregularity of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, complex, projective variety (/$\mathbb C$). Let us define the irregularity of $X$ to be  $q(X):= h^1(\mathcal O_X)$.

Note that  $X=\mathbb P^n$ is regular by above definition as $q(\mathbb P^n)= h^1(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n})=0$. Also note that by Euler exact sequence we have $h^0(\Omega_{\mathbb P^n})=0$. Therefore for $\mathbb P^n$ one has $q(\mathbb P^n)= h^1(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n})=h^0(\Omega_{\mathbb P^n})=0$.

My question is that, is it true that for a any smooth complex projective variety one has $q(X)=h^1(\mathcal O_X)=h^0(\Omega_{ X})$. Does it follow from some standard sequence?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Yes and this is part of Hodge theory.

Comment: @CraniumClamp, Thanks. Can you give a specific reference where this equality is discussed?

Comment: Literally any book on complex geometry - Griffiths and Harris, Huybrecths all have it